# Determines Types from Arguments

Tags: typescript

I have a function that calls an external api and returns data based on the params sent. I'm trying to type this function but having some difficulty.

```js
import axios from 'axios';

interface IGetContactArgs {
  properties?: string[];
}

interface IResponse {
  id: number,
  properties: {
    [index: string]: any;
  }
}

const getContact = (id: number, params?: IGetContactArgs) => {
  return axios.get<IResponse>(`URL/${id}`, { params });
}
```

An example invocation of this function would be...

```js
const data = await getContact(0, { properties: ['name', 'img' ] });
```

Which would return...

```js
{
  "id": 0,
  "properties": {
     "name": "John",
     "img": "https://imageurl.com/image",
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to type this than what I'm doing so that the resultant object has the type that is determined by in the inputs to the function?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be better. You can use [generics][1] to do that.

What it seems to me is you're passing properties from some type. Let's say Content

> You can define what values properties will take in the array and what will be response type as per the `Content` type.

I just extracted the given type in the parameter and assign it to the response.

---

```
import axios from 'axios';

interface ContentType {
   name: string;
   img: string;
}

interface IResponse<T extends keyof ContentType> {
  id: number,
    properties: Record<T, any>;
}

const getContact = <T extends keyof ContentType>(id: number, params?: {properties: T[]}) => {
  return axios.get<IResponse<T>>(`URL/${id}`, { params });
}
```

```
const data = await getContact(0, { properties: ['name'] });
```

---

`Content` type ensures that you can't pass some random string into the properties, and using generics.

---

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQwB7AgZzgMyhEcDkyqa+A3AFDnAB2MAplJggMZ1wDCEtdtAKgJ5g2Ab3Jxx1BCDoAuOGhhQaAcwri4oZXIVLqq8gF9KNeoxZsAkgCU6aSNTR0APLzh0k9agBMMAazr8EJgcXJ4wAkIAfHCi4sBectQAriAARgwANGLqYDhCsMC2cjbM0F4uGYjU-JEURuSlDvDKdDCctCzwALxwLm4ePD5w-oHB7WERdJEAFPGJKelQlWAIUFJoAPxywrkQ+TCFaHK8ANoAugYAlHBd0bFwUK1JUNSIKOgAdC0wTta29o4XJEZgADACqVgAMgB6AAkwniBhBlWEcBWaxAGCudUoDS4CjgXgQMAQN0QAHcEMBmq1xp1pgAGFFovIMA5FOAnfCSaT4M5wbFAA)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what you mean, but if you do like this

```
function getContact<T extends number, S extends string>(
  id: T,
  params: { properties: S[] }
): {
  id: T;
  properties: {
    [K in S]: string;
  };
} {
  return {} as any;
}

// type is { id: 0; properties: { "hi": string; "you": string; } }
const u = getContact(0, { properties: ["hi", "you"] });
```

then all the type will be inferred from the invocation without you needing to write any other interfaces.